# Does $X\sim B(Y1,\delta)$ first-order stochastically dominate(FSD) $W\sim B(Y0,\delta)$ when $Y1$ FSD $Y0$

Tags: stochastic-analysis

It is very straightforward to prove $X\sim Binomial(n+1,\delta)$ first-order stochastically dominate $W\sim Binomial(n,\delta)$. However, is it also true that  $X\sim B(Y1,\delta)$ first-order stochastically dominate(FSD) $W\sim B(Y0,\delta)$ when $Y1$ first-order stochastically dominate $Y0$? That is, in the latter case, $Y1$ and $Y0$ are random variables.

Comment: Obviously yes, simply select some random variables $Z_i\sim Y_i$ such that $Z_1\geqslant Z_0$ almost surely and compare Binomial$(Z_1,\delta)$ and Binomial$(Z_0,\delta)$.

Comment: @Did Thank you. But I have some difficulty in proving this little bit more formally.

Comment: Which part? Please be specific.

Comment: @Did How can I compare Binomial($Z_1,\delta$) with Binomial($Z_0,\delta$)  where $Z_1>Z_0$ almost surely.

Comment: Well, realize every Bin$(n,\delta)$ simultaneously as $\sum\limits_{k=1}^nU_k$ from a single i.i.d. Bernoulli sequence $(U_k)$ independent of $(Z_0,Z_1)$, then $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{Z_1}U_k\geqslant\sum\limits_{k=1}^{Z_0}U_k$ with full probability.

Comment: @Did Thank you very much.